# TeamCity commit status publisher with BitBucket two factor auth

Tags: bitbucket, teamcity

How do I send the status of a TeamCity build to a BitBucket Cloud pull request when two factor auth is enabled?

I've created a BitBucket app password and added the credentials to a "Commit status publisher" build feature:

[image]

This results in:

> Bitbucket Cloud publisher has failed to connect to "git@bitbucket.org:teamname/reponame.git" repository: HTTP response error, response code: 401, reason: Unauthorized

Based on the [documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Commit+Status+Publisher) I have ensured the server url is fully qualified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functionality works exactly as expected. I made the mistake of using the label and password for the generated app password. Instead, I should have used my BitBucket username and just the generated password. The label isn't used as part of the authentication.

Comment: Could you use your own user account or was it a team-account name that you used? I'me getting "401 unauthorized" when using my own user account together with an "app password".